# transparent background in figure (matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'd like to save a matlab figure with transparent background, on mac, and import into Keynote.

This question was asked in 2013, but I understand matlab has changed its graphics handling since then.  Is there a 'good' way to do this?  The plotting syntax is so scattered and overloaded.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/transparent-labels) could be relevant somehow (see "_3 simple steps_", and also _Related posts:_ )...

Answer (score 1):

I looked for this myself some time ago. Mathworks seems to state that this is not directly possible in matlab and that it isn't a feature they plan on introducing as well:

http://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19907-transparent-background-for-figures

But as stated in the link it can easily be achieved using a third-party program (for example inkscape, which is freeware(opensource?) program) if you export the figure as a .eps or .pdf. This basically enables you to directly edit or delete certain parts of the image.

This is probably not exactly what you were looking for, but I know of no easier native solution than this. However the author refers to  [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) which might directly solve you porblem (I don't have any experience using it, sorry).

Comment: Thanks, I saw this as well... I know they changed graphics handling since then and was hoping there was now a solution.